# Javascript regular expression to remove domain extention

Tags: javascript

I would like a regex that can remove the domain extension from a string e.g.  The string is from a text field so the user may or may not include `http://www.`

```
var fqdn = "http://www.mydomainname.com";

var name = regex_function(fqdn);

// name === "mydomainname"
```

Comment: What is the expected output in your example?

Comment: @PaulS. They have it at the bottom. `name` should contain "mydomainname"

Comment: What about `something.org.uk`?

Comment: `http://www.example.com`, `http://foo.example.com` and `http://example.com` may all have different content

Comment: @Quentin don't forget about `example.us`, `example.it`, `example.de`, etc.

Comment: You might struggle with this. You can do `.com`, `.gov` etc. easily enough, but what about `.co.uk`, `.uk.com` (it exists), `.com.au` and others?

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 main ways to do this: [with regular expressions](https://github.com/allmarkedup/purl/blob/master/purl.js) and with using the DOM.

```
function regex_function(fqdn) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = fqdn;
    return a.hostname || undefined;
}
```

There's no reliable way to remove domain extensions like `.com`, but why would you do that anyway?

This function does remove a few extensions, but please ***DO NOT*** use this, I just added it here to show you how much work and unnecessary code is required to even get close to removing a small portion of these extensions:

```
function removeExt(str){
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = str;
    var hostName = a.hostname;
    var domainExtensions = [
        "gov", "org", "co", "com", "in", "info", "net", "uk", "af", "am", "ar", "au", "as", "az", "be", "bg", "bn", "bo", "bs", "ca", "cs", "cy", "da", "de", "dv", "el", "en", "es", "et", "eu", "fa", "fi", "fo", "fr", "gd", "gl", "gn", "gu", "he", "hi", "hr", "hu", "hy", "id", "is", "it", "jp", "ka", "kk", "km", "kn", "ko", "ks", "la", "lo", "lt", "lv", "mi", "mk", "ml", "mn", "mr", "ms", "mt", "my", "nb", "ne", "nl", "or", "pa", "pl", "pt", "rm", "ro", "ru", "sa", "sb", "sd", "si", "sk", "sl", "so", "sq", "sr", "sv", "sw", "ta", "te", "tg", "th", "tk", "tn", "tr", "ts", "tt", "uk", "ur", "uz", "vi", "xh", "yi", "zh", "zu"
    ];
    var regex = new RegExp("\.?(\."+domainExtensions.join('|')+")+$");
    return hostName.replace(regex,'');
}
```

Comment: I like this solution! However, for messy input it returned `'newtab'` in Chrome and the current host in Firefox.

Comment: @marsze Of course you need to validate your input first, but that was not the question here.

Comment: And what if there was no DOM? Like nodejs.

Comment: @DanLee [There are ways to get around that as well.](http://marksoper.me/Server-side-DOM-manipulation-in-Nodejs-with-JSDOM-JQuery-and-Mustache-Templates-April-25-2011.html)

Comment: @DJDavid98 Seems like a *huge* overhead for just getting the domain name, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

Not so elegant, but it is working, in most regular cases- it seems:

```
function strip(fqdn) {

        fqdn=fqdn.replace(/http:\/\/www./,'');
    var i = fqdn.lastIndexOf('.');
    var n=fqdn.substr(i,fqdn.length-1);
    fqdn=fqdn.replace(n,'');

    dot=fqdn.lastIndexOf('.');

    if(dot!=-1) {
    var n2=fqdn.substr(dot,fqdn.length-1);
    fqdn=fqdn.replace(n2,'');   
    }

    return fqdn;

}
```

Better one:

```
function strip_dom(fqdn) {

    pattern=/\.+[0-9A-Za-z]+\./;
    fqdn=fqdn.match(pattern);

    fqdn=fqdn.join(fqdn,'');

    fqdn=fqdn.replace(/\./g,'');

    return fqdn;


}
```

Not working for subdomains (separated by dot), but with few tweaks...